# How to read Registry keys in Windows 10 IOT Core OS?

Tags: windows, operating-system, iot, windows-10-iot-core

I am installing one Enterprise software based on type of Windows OS . but i am not able to read any specific registry keys for Windows 10 IOT core OS, Could you please help on this

Answer (score 0):

It seems accessing registry on Windows IoT Core programmatically can't be done. Either via UWP or Win32.

Related topics: "[How to read registry in windows 10 universal app.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/51f12da0-ce81-4dbf-bafe-1cba5af2fb15/how-to-read-registry-in-windows-10-universal-app?forum=wpdevelop)"

The following code works on Desktop but result in exception Windows IoT Core:

```
        try
        {
            using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon"))
            {
                if (key != null)
                {
                    Object o = key.GetValue("BuildNumber");
                    if (o != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Current Build version: " + o.ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("key.GetValue return NULL!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)  
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

> Attempt by method 'ReadRegistry.Program.Main(System.String[])' to
>   access field 'Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser' failed.

About this issue you can submit a **feedback** via feedback hub.

**Workaround** is using command line like [powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/connect-your-device/powershell):

[image]

Comment: Hi Rita Han, When we don't have any Registry keys in Windows 10 IOT Core OS  then how we can figure out and skip Application. Could you explain a little bit more on this.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @Praveenkumar But your question is "How to read Registry keys in Windows 10 IOT Core OS?" So what actual problem of installing the Enterprise software?

Comment: Actual problem is, I need to run my application only on Windows 10 IOT Core OS only, if we try to run on IOT Enterprise OS then i need to skip this application launch process by checking the some condition.                           My initial understanding is we can do with Registry check but, if we don't have registry keys then what is the alternate way to find the type of Windows 10 IOT OS we are trying to run my Application.

Comment: @Praveenkumar Maybe you can detect the OS type in your application then exist instead of launching. What's kind of your application type, UWP?

Comment: I want to run one Windows application, which need to be supported for Windows 10 IOT Core OS only, if they trying to run on Windows 10 IOT Enterprise Edition then i want to skip it.

Comment: @Praveenkumar You can use [GetProductInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getproductinfo) API to determine the system type. For example: `GetProductInfo(10, 0, 0, 0, &type);` the `type` will be 4 on Windows 10 Enterprise and 123 on Windows 10 IoT Core.